# how to remove appliation which install from snap in ubunutu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, snapcraft

i have installed some applications using snapcraft which is very innovative concept.but , now i want to uninstall some of application. I had some stuff but did`nt get proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question should be in the askubuntu site, but regardless. A simple google search will reveal that all you have to do is `sudo snap remove <package-name>`. More info here https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/uninstall-software-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Thanks. I got same solution as you mentioned.

Comment: @MiteshVasava In that case can you mark this answer as correct? That way if google results change this response will still point to that site and if not, the command itself is in the answer